# what does this mean in grunt regarding autoprefixer plugin?

Tags: gruntjs, autoprefixer

I have installed a number of plugins in grunt but I am receiving this message:

*"local Npm module "grunt-autoprefixer" not found. Is it installed?"*

I checked my node- modules folder and there is no autoprefixer file in there, but there are files for all my other plugins. Is this the problem? If so, how can I fix this? Do I have to reinstall the plugin?

I"m a beginner so any simple answers would be greatly appreciated. (dumb it down! lol).

Comment: `npm install grunt-autoprefixer --save-dev` and make sure you have valid package.json.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @raidendev! I was trying to figure out how to run grunt on my .less files _without_ autoprefixing and your response helped.  I simply ran:
`npm uninstall grunt-autoprefixer --save-dev`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer. For some reason everytime I copy and paste the json file and the grunt file to a new project the autoprefixer folder in the node moldules folder was not copied over. I'm not sure why this happens, but the fix is to just copy and past the autoprefixer folder into the new node modules folder!